# Centering resizable images in recursive divs with CSS

Tags: theming

I'm working on theming an image gallery content type I created through which a user uploads several images and as a result see a list of images on the page.

I use Responsive Images and Styles module so the images don't have a fixed size. The effect I want to have is that these images align in a row and are always centered, having equal spaces/gutter width between them, regardless of browser resizing. So adding media queries the final result will be a one column page, so one image top of another, in iPhone viewport and three-four column page, images lying side by side, on a desktop screen.

The complicated part is Drupal has so many divs one inside another and I'm not sure if I'm following the right steps to achieve this effect. Though it could be simple it became problematic with these recursive divs.

So if someone can guide me through these divs and help me figure out how to achieve this aligment I would be really grateful. Every reply is important for me so don't hesitate to come up with comments and solutions of every kind.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Drupal 7

Comment: I suppose you are using views to achieve this? You can edit style settings of view fields... So you can add your own css classes to every image you display. Thay way you can safely use one class, and you will be sure it is re-used all the time.

Comment: Thank you Neograph. Yes, I use Views but only for one page. The gallery page is a drupal core content type node page. In fact I deciphered all the divs but I don't know well where to begin because they are a bit too much :) So I would like to know if there is a common practice to approach them, like beginning from a certain div or something like that.

Comment: It's depending on your chosen template, so there is no right or wrong. (therefor I'd recommend the views approach, it will keep working even if you change template later)

Comment: You might want to answer the question yourself, the road you took to achieve the goal. That way others won't have to ask the question again. You can then accept your own answer 2 days later so the question will be marked as 'answered' :)